# How to copy Files from One folder to another using third folder as a reference ? (Ubuntu/Linux/rsync)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, rsync, copy

OS - Ubuntu Linux , Utility preferred - rsync

Is it possible to copy all files from first folder (1/folder) to the third folder (3/folder) that are newer than or not existing in the second folder (2/folder) with the same directory structure ?

I don't want any hard links in the third folder.

I have tried the below but couldn't get it to work

```
rsync -av --link-dest /2/folder root@s1:/1/folder /3/.
```

What I am doing now is copying the full folder and then delete duplicates from the third folder by comparing it with the second folder

```
rsync -av root@s1:/1/folder /3/.
fdupes -r -d -N -o name //2/folder /3/folder
find /3/folder -type d -empty -delete
```

Obviously that takes double the space, double the bandwidth and double the time.

Direct approach would be appreciated.

I have tried some other scripts and tools like (rdiff-backup etc) but unable to get it to work.

Thanks.

Edit:

I was also wondering if it is possible to use rsync to get the file list to copy between 1/ and 2/ into a text file, and then replace 2/ with 3/ in it and use it to copy manually ?

Answer (score 0):

This one is a bit obstruse to me, and tbh, sounds like an XY-Problem.

But anyway:

One way to accomplish this, would be to use `find` to get a list of all files relative to ./2/ that are newer than time X, and pipe that to `cp` or ´rsync´.
You will however run into 'missing target directory' issues, as cp will only copy the base file. To counter that you could, before copying the files, create all parent directories with `mkdir -p`

Putting it all together would look something like this:

```sh
function cpbyref() {
    cd ./2
    ref=$(find -type f -cmin -TIMESINCELASTRUNINMINUTES )
    cd -
    echo $ref | xargs -i sh -c 'mkdir -p ./1/"${1%/*}/"; cp ./1/"$1" ./3/"$1"' '--' '{}'
}
```

> I wrote this out of my head, didnt test it, and you probably will need to fumble around with some of it, but it should give you a rough idea how to do it

Comment: Thank you for the lead, this is a good idea as well, only thing I can see is to find in 1/ as that is the one which is changing, I will try this approach and post the results.

Answer (score 0):

This command will implement your requirement assuming that the specified directories `1`, `2`, `3` are in the current directory (`$PWD`). This isn't necessary for the source and destination, but the comparison directory path is relative to the destination so we have to make it an absolute path:

```
rsync --dry-run -av --update --compare-dest="$PWD"/2/folder/ "$PWD"/1/folder/ "$PWD"/3/folder/
```

Worked scenario

```
mkdir -p {1,2,3}/folder    # 1=src, 2=cmp, 3=dst
date >2/folder/date
ps -f >1/folder/ps-f
who >1/folder/who
cp -p 1/folder/who 2/folder/who
cp -p 1/folder/ps-f 3/folder/ps-f
sleep 1
date >1/folder/date

tree {1,2,3}/folder
1/folder
├── date
├── ps-f
└── who
2/folder
├── date
└── who
3/folder
└── ps-f
```

We now have a set of example file pairs, where `date` is different but `who` and `ps-f` are the same.

```
rsync --dry-run -av --update --compare-dest="$PWD"/2/folder/ 1/folder/ 3/folder/
sending incremental file list
./
date

sent 123 bytes  received 23 bytes  292.00 bytes/sec
total size is 181  speedup is 1.24 (DRY RUN)
```

You can see from the output that `rsync` would have transferred just the single file changed `date`. Everything else is left unchanged, including that because `who` in the source matches `who` in the comparison directory it *is not* transferred to the destination.

As ever, remove `--dry-run` to allow `rsync` to execute its plan rather than just show it.